# JavaFX print node at specific size

Tags: javafx, clojure

I'm creating a book of printed puzzles for a family member by adapting a previously-written desktop program to print the puzzles. I need each puzzle to print at a specific size, 5" square in this case. I can't seem to find a way to reliably do so programmatically.

Here is an implementation which scales the canvas where the puzzle is drawn using a scaling factor determined by trial and error. This is written in Clojure, but I thing it is also understandable by anyone who uses Java.

```
(defn create-print-button-click-handler
  "Handle a click on the 'Print...' button."
  [canvas stage]
  (reify EventHandler
    (handle [this event]
      (if false
        (batch-print)
        ;; else
        (let [job (PrinterJob/createPrinterJob)]
          (if (.showPrintDialog job stage)
            (let [printer (.getPrinter job)
                  job-settings (.getJobSettings job)
                  ;; Margin settings are in points. Set to half inch left margin,
                  ;; 3/4 inch for the rest.
                  layout (.createPageLayout printer Paper/NA_LETTER PageOrientation/PORTRAIT
                                            36.0 54.0 54.0 54.0)
                  printable-width (.getPrintableWidth layout)
                  printable-height (.getPrintableHeight layout)
                  printer-dpi (.getFeedResolution (.getPrintResolution job-settings))
                  dots-across (* printer-dpi 5) ;; five inches
                  cnvs (Canvas. dots-across dots-across)
                  scale 0.25]
              (.setPrintColor job-settings PrintColor/MONOCHROME)
              (.setPageLayout job-settings layout)
              ;; Scale by the same amount along both axes.
              (.add (.getTransforms cnvs) (Scale. scale scale))
              ;; This ugliness is because I want to print the background completely white.
              ;; Since we are using the same function to draw the board to the screen and
              ;; to the canvas for printing, we need to change the background before
              ;; drawing then back afterwards.
              (def board-color (Color/web "#ffffff"))
              (redraw-board cnvs)
              (def board-color (Color/web board-web-color))
              (.printPage job cnvs)
              (.endJob job))))))))
```

I've seen some examples that use the printable width and height, but I haven't gotten understandable results (too big to fit page).

Like I said, this works, but I would like the program to respond correctly when other printers are used that might have different resolutions, differing horizontal and vertical resolutions, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've come up with something that seems to work. Here's an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows how to do it.

```
(ns printscaling.core
  (:gen-class
   :extends javafx.application.Application)
  (:import
   [javafx.application Application]
   [javafx.beans.value ChangeListener]
   [javafx.event EventHandler]
   [javafx.geometry Insets Pos]
   [javafx.print PrinterJob]
   [javafx.scene Scene]
   [javafx.scene.canvas Canvas]
   [javafx.scene.control Button]
   [javafx.scene.layout BorderPane Pane Region VBox]
   [javafx.scene.paint Color]
   [javafx.scene.transform Scale]
   [javafx.stage Screen]))

(def points-per-inch 72.0)

(defn redraw-board
  "Draw the board on the canvas."
  [canvas]
  (let [w (.getWidth canvas)
        h (.getHeight canvas)
        gc (.getGraphicsContext2D canvas)]
    
    (doto gc
      (.clearRect 0 0 w h)
      (.setLineWidth 3)
      (.setFill (Color/BLUE))
      (.setStroke (Color/BLUE))
      (.strokeRect 0 0 w h)
      (.strokeLine 0 0 w h)
      (.strokeLine w 0 0 h))))

(defn create-print-button-handler
  "Handle a click on the 'Print' button. Print a 5 inch square version
   of the board."
  [stage]
  (reify EventHandler
    (handle [this event]
      (let [job (PrinterJob/createPrinterJob)]
        (if (.showPrintDialog job stage)
          (let [dpi (.getDpi (Screen/getPrimary))
                pixels (* dpi 5)
                canvas (Canvas. pixels pixels)
                scale (/ points-per-inch dpi)]
            (.add (.getTransforms canvas) (Scale. scale scale))
            (redraw-board canvas)
            (if (.printPage job canvas)
              (.endJob job))))))))

(defn create-print-btn [stage]
  (let [btn (Button. "Print")]
    (.setOnAction btn (create-print-button-handler stage))
    btn))

(defn -start
  "Build the application interface and start it up."
  [this stage]
  (let [root (BorderPane.)
        center (Pane.)
        spacer (Region.)
        btn-pane (VBox.)
        scene (Scene. root)
        canvas (Canvas.)
        print-btn (create-print-btn stage)]

    (doto (.widthProperty canvas)
      (.bind (.widthProperty center))
      (.addListener
       (reify ChangeListener
         (changed [_ _ _ _]
           (redraw-board canvas)))))
    (doto (.heightProperty canvas)
      (.bind (.heightProperty center))
      (.addListener
       (reify ChangeListener
         (changed [_ _ _ _]
           (redraw-board canvas)))))
    
    (doto btn-pane
      (.setId "btn-pane")
      (.setPadding (Insets. 10))
      (.setAlignment Pos/CENTER)
      (.setStyle "-fx-background-color: slategray;"))

    (.setPrefHeight spacer Integer/MAX_VALUE)
    (.addAll (.getChildren btn-pane) [print-btn spacer])

    (.add (.getChildren  center) canvas)
    (.setCenter root center)
    (.setRight root btn-pane)

    (doto stage
      (.setTitle "Print Scaling")
      (.setScene scene)
      (.setHeight 400)
      (.setWidth 600)
      (.show))))

(defn -main [& args]
  (Application/launch printscaling.core args))
```

In the example, the program just draws a box with two diagonals for the board representation on the screen.

When the user clicks the print button, the program creates a new `Canvas` object to use for printing. It sizes that canvas based on the dpi of the display screen. In my case I wanted a 5" square board printed out, so that's what the `(* dpi 5)` calculates in terms of pixels on the display. The same function used to draw the board on the screen is used to draw it on the specially created `Canvas`.

The trick to scaling was simply to use a scaling factor based on the ratio of printers points per inch (72) to the dpi of the display (commonly 96, 120, or more). Adding that scaling factor to the transforms used on the `Canvas` causes the board to be printed at the desired size. This worked correctly with printers with different resolutions.

This has not been tested with multiple display devices with different dpi, so I would be eager to hear if anyone gets incorrect (or correct) results using this method on such devices.